# How to get the title to print

Tags: python

if we are given this code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'title author year price')
favorite = Book('Adventures of Sherlock Holmes',
                'Arthur Conan Doyle', 1892, 21.50)
another = Book('Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes', 
               'Arthur Conan Doyle', 1894, 23.50)
still_another = Book('Return of Sherlock Holmes',
                     'Arthur Conan Doyle', 1905, 25.00)
```

how do you get the title of the book in the variable  still_another to print?

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
print(still_another.title)
```

Each value in a `namedtuple` can be accessed via its name and in your case the title can be accessed via `.title`.

Comment: Likewise `still_another[0]` since title happens to be defined first. NamedTuples support integer indices, for completeness, though the attribute access (as in this answer) is often clearer and what you want.